# how to unblock browser when using while loop?

Tags: php, long-polling

i make an ajax request to a php file that runs a while loop that looks for new data in the database, but i cant give it new data because the browser is blocked while waiting for the new data.

does anyone know how to not block the browser?

Comment: Guess he wants a ob_flush (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) to display as it goes or so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't actually make an *Asynchronous*-JAX request, but rather a synchronous one.

If you're using a Javascript library, most of them have a boolean flag for whether or not the request should be asynchronous - make sure you're not choosing synchronous by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous. To avoid this kind of issue. It seems you're not doing an Ajax request, but a synchrone request. What is your syntax ? Have you a piece of code to show ?